# PlayFramework - Java: Entity class is not abstract and does not override _ebean_intercept() method

Tags: java, playframework, entity, ebean, playframework-2.5

Basically I have simple domain object like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sample_entity")
public class SampleEntity extends Model 
{    
   @Id 
   private Long id;
   private String name;

   @ManyToOne
   private User user;

   //constructors, getters and setters
}
```

And when I'am trying to run my Play application I'm getting an error described in title. I've checked all imports and they seems to be good. I have no idea what's wrong here. Before I add some domain objects my application worked... (with only User domain object)

Comment: Any other special fields in the domain - N-to-Many, etc.? From which package is the `Model` class that you are extending?

Comment: Yes, I have @ManyToOne relation inside domain. Model is from correct PlayFramework libraries, I've chcecked it.

Comment: To confirm - the `Model` class you're extending is `com.avaje.ebean.Model`?

Answer (score 0):

"Sbt clean" and update project worked for me

Answer (score -1):

Basically the problem was "trivial" - something cached...

Comment: I get this problem intermittently on a regular basis. I change some *other* class, and I get exactly the same model classes every time complaining that they are missing this autogenerated method.

Deleting the class files in question (so that they must be recompiled) does not fix the issue. Only cleaning the project seems to fix it.

It was a problem way back in version 4, and its still a problem now in version 6 (I can't upgrade any further because of my play framework version).